# Replcae multiple substrings in dataframe column based on other columns

Tags: dataframe, replace, substring

I'm stuck. I need a (deceptive) simple operation on a tibble...

One of the columns is a string. I also have `vars` that is a char vector that matches names on tibble.

So I need to replace all my `vars` in `my_tib$thestring` by the corresponding value in the tibble.

Here is an example

```
  vars <- c("Yes", "No", "Maybe")
  
  my_tib <- tribble(
    ~Yes, ~No, ~Maybe, ~thestring,
    1,     0,   2    , "Sometimes Yes is YES",
    1,     0,   3    , "Sometimes Yes others is No or Maybe",
    1,     0,   4    , "Sometimes Yes while Maybe...",
    1,     0,   5    , "Sometimes Yes is Yes and No and maybe",
  )
  
  # Intended Result
  my_tib_result <- tribble(
    ~yes, ~no, ~maybe, ~thestring,
    1,     0,   2    , "Sometimes 1 is YES",
    1,     0,   3    , "Sometimes 1 others is 0 or 3",
    1,     0,   4    , "Sometimes 1 while 4...",
    1,     0,   5    , "Sometimes 1 is 1 and 0 and 5",
  )
```

I'm sure it's simple (:) or not :))... but I'm not moving from this point... so I need a Most welcome push.

Thank you very much for your comments and help.

AC

Answer (score 0):

I have found a method... not the most elegant, but it works... so sharing the solution.

If any one has a better idea I would appreciatte.

My solution:

```
  # Create a function
  chg_each <- function(str, tb){
    tb %>% mutate(
    # Note the 'as.character' and 'get' ... for map2
      text = map2(text, as.character(get(str)),
                  ~if_else(is.na(.x), "",
                           str_replace_all(.x, str, .y)))
  }

# Iterate over all vars to change
end_my_tib <- my_tib
for(var in vars){
    end_my_tib <- chg_each (var, end_my_tib)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).